# SQL Joining multiple records

Tags: sql

Basically I have a poorly designed SQL table that I am not able to modify that I need to pull data from.
The table is structured as:

```
filename | code
---------+------
     A   |   56
     A   |   43
     A   |   21
     B   |   32
     B   |   11
```

I need to be able to query for files from specific combinations of codes.
Like `SELECT filename FROM table WHERE code = 56 and code <> 43` and that will display all filenames that have a code 56 and do not have a code 43. There can be any number of codes and all the codes will be different for every file. Is this possible with an SQL statement without modifying the database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select filename
from t
group by filename
having sum(case when code = 56 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- has 56
       sum(case when code = 43 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;     -- no 43
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where  
  exists (select 1 from tablename where filename = t.filename and code = 56)
  and
  not exists (select 1 from tablename where filename = t.filename and code = 43)
```

If your database supports an operator like [`EXCEPT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you could also do it like this:

```
select * from tablename
where filename in (
  select filename where code = 56
  except
  select filename where code = 43 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists and distinct:

```
select distinct filename
from t as t1
where exists(select * from t where t.filename=t1.filename and t.code=56)
and not exists(select * from t where t.filename=t1.filename and t.code=43)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Having and group by clause:

```
SELECT FILENAME FROM TABLE1
WHERE CODE IN (56, 43)
GROUP BY FILENAME
HAVING MAX(CODE) = min(code) and MIN(CODE) = 56;
```